# how to make hbase respect hregion.max.filesize for existent regions data

Tags: hbase

I am using the default configuration for HBase.  I have a lot of regions for each region server.

I've found that I can configure the maximum size of region - not to be 256MB but for 4GB for example.  So I've added the following configuration and restarted cluster:

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.hregion.max.filesize</name>
    <value>4294967296</value>
</property>
```

Then I've executed major_compaction - but nothing happened.

How can I force HBase to merge hfiles to respect this configuration for existing data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things here, I think you should restart atleast the Hmaster to pick up the changed value.
Also I have set the byte value, in your case it should be 4294967296 (4GB).
I think after these changes Hbase should manually split the regions bigger than the specified max.filesize. Or else you can also do a manual major_compact or even split.

Comment: I did restarted all cluster, and also configured the value in bytes, run a major_compaction. But unfortunately nothing happens

Comment: I thought that it should merge, but nothing happens

Answer (score 4):

Compaction merges StoreFiles, it doesn't merge regions.

You can manually merge existing regions using:

```
$ bin/hbase org.apache.hbase.util.Merge <tablename> <region1> <region2>
```

There are some tools and patches available that make implicit region merging possible.

Have a look here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-7846